# Relate database and PHP through links

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I'm doing a code where the main page has titles of some exercises: 'Exercises.php' (stored in a Mysql database) and depending on what title the user clicks (with links), I want the title and the question itself in another page: ‘question.php’. The questions will also be taken from the database. Im trying to use a GET parameter in the exercise link with the id of the exercise. Then in ‘question.php’, get the exercise with that id from the database.

This is some of the code that I've done so far but I'm stuck. Could you help me?
Thank you.

Exercises.php – In here I have all of the titles of the exercises displayed.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>

<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["exercise_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><a name="search" href="http://localhost/PHP%20Pages/2.php" target="_blank"><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["difficulty"]; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

question.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises"; /*Select from table name: exercises*/
$result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/


    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " .  $row["title"] . $row["text"] . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: Im trying to use a GET parameter in the exercise link with the id of the exercise. Then in ‘question.php’, get the exercise with that id from the database.  -- did you tried using GET?

Comment: I don't see where you tried to use a GET array anywhere. Can you tell us what it is that you want us to help you with?

Comment: if you need any other info please comment i will help you on how  to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `excericise_id` from excercise.php you can change your `href` like this

```
<a href="question.php?id=<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>" role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>
```

And  you can get that exercise id in your `question.php` page like this

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

I would like you to suggest you to keep your db connection in separate file and try to include and use. that is not the good way to write database connection in every page.